# Trying to decide between two ways of connecting a hidden signal in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Let's say we have three classes, `A`, `B`, and `C`. `B` holds a private instance of `A`, and `C` holds an instance of `B` (i.e. `C` -> `B` -> `A`). `C` needs to receive an `update()` signal from `A`, but since `A` is private, we can either:

---

Use an accessor method in `B` to allow access to `A`'s `update()` signal. For example,

in `C`:

```
 connect(B.getA(), SIGNAL(update()), this, SLOT(doUpdate()));
```

---

Alternatively, we could forward `A`'s `update()` signal in `B` to `C`. For example,

in `B`:

```
connect(A, SIGNAL(update()), this, SIGNAL(update()));
```

and in `C`:

```
connect(B, SIGNAL(update()), this, SLOT(doUpdate()));
```

---

Or, some other option that I'm completely missing; not sure.

Basically, what are the differences between the two options? Neither way breaks encapsulation, but will there be latency that is introduced by having a forwarded signal? The documentation says that the second signal is sent as soon as the first is received, so it doesn't seem like there would be much of a difference, but I'm curious about whether there is a 'right' way to do it.

---

Oh, and I realize that "hidden" in the title isn't really accurate, but I can't think of a better way of phrasing it without getting too wordy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A signal that is emitted in the same thread is just a call (unless you ask explicitly to use a queue), so from a performance point of view the cost is negligible unless you're creating a lot (millions) of signals per second (and in that case probably using signals is a bad idea anyway). If this is needed for GUI-related machinery then the cost is most probably irrelevant as drawing a single character in the GUI costs much more.

About encapsulation it's hard to tell without knowing more about `A`, `B` or `C`... the fact that `C` wants to be notified about something that happens in the hidden guts of `B` sounds strange... may be `B` should instead derive from `A` or at least republish that signal anyway from a logical point of view?

Comment: Perhaps I simplified the problem too much. `B` has a few instances of `A`, each in their own thread. `C` is the GUI which contains a widget that needs to be updated by `B`'s `A` objects, but not any one in particular. So `B` needs to generate a signal each time any of its `A` objects updates. Does that change anything?

Comment: @Thomas: in this case couldn't be `B` make the connection instead of making it from `C`?

Answer (score 1):

I personally would connect the A's signals to a (duplicate) `update` signal in B. That way you hide B's implementation from C and can change the internal mechanism later on. It's not an overly elaborate form of it, but the `connect(B.getA(), SIGNAL(update()), this, SLOT(doStuff()))` version in C smells a bit of [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).